# How run Pig jobs in sequence one by one

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

I have requirement to run pig jobs in sequence without manual interaction .
**Could you please advise me is there anyway to automate pig jobs by using pig / some other way**
Assume jobs :

JOB001
JOB002
JOB003
JOB004

JOB001   -- Is my 1 st  JOB  --> after successful run 'JOB001' It should trigger 'JOB002'
JOB002   --> after successful run 'JOB002' It should trigger 'JOB003'
JOB003   --> after successful run 'JOB003' It should trigger 'JOB004'.

Answer (score 1):

Oozie is the tool for you.

Simply create a workflow connecting one Pig job to another.

Answer (score 0):

[oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/) is designed to schedule the hadoop jobs. see [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OOZIE/Pig+Cookbook) for running pig jobs in oozie. [Quick start](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.1/index.html) help you to begin with oozie.